# Percorrer um vetor dividindo a busca em threads

Tags: c, c++, thread, multithreading

Olá, estou com um problema, estou com uma tarefa da faculdade onde eu tenho um vetor muito grande, onde eu tenho que fazer com que cada thread do processador percorra uma parte desse vetor aumentando a velocidade da busca, porém quando executo meu código, aparece 2 vezes o printf do valor no vetor 0, eu não sei pq, acredito que deva estar ocorrendo alguma condição de corrida ainda, mas não sei aonde.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define TAM 100000000

long *vetor;
long cont=0;
int vet[3];
sem_t semaforo;

void preencher(){
    long i;
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++) vetor[i]=rand()%TAM;
}

void contar(void *argp) {
    int i, temp;
    int alvo;
    alvo = (long) argp;
    sem_wait(&semaforo);
    vet[0] = (TAM/4);
    printf("VALOR NO VETOR[0]=%d\n", vet[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < vet[0]; i++) {
    if(vetor[i]==alvo){

        temp = cont;
        temp++;
        cont = temp;

     }
    }
    sem_post(&semaforo);
}

void contar2(void *argp) {
        int i, temp;
        int alvo;
        alvo = (long) argp;
        sem_wait(&semaforo);
        vet[1] = (TAM/2);
        printf("VALOR NO VETOR[1]=%d\n", vet[1]);
        for (i = vet[0]; i < vet[1]; i++) {
        if(vetor[i]==alvo){

            temp = cont;
            temp++;
            cont = temp;

         }
        }
        sem_post(&semaforo);
}

void contar3(void *argp) {
        int i, temp;
        int alvo;
        alvo = (long) argp;
        sem_wait(&semaforo);
        vet[2] = (TAM/4)*3;
        printf("VALOR NO VETOR[2]=%d\n", vet[2]);
        for (i = vet[1]; i < vet[2]; i++) {
        if(vetor[i]==alvo){

            temp = cont;
            temp++;
            cont = temp;

         }
        }
        sem_post(&semaforo);
}

void contar4(void *argp) {
        int i, temp;
        int alvo;
        alvo = (long) argp;
        sem_wait(&semaforo);
        for (i = vet[2]; i < TAM; i++) {
        if(vetor[i]==alvo){

            temp = cont;
            temp++;
            cont = temp;

         }
        }
        sem_post(&semaforo);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t t1, t2, t3, t4;
    sem_init(&semaforo,0,1);
    long chave;
    vetor = (long *)malloc(TAM*sizeof(long));
    preencher();
    printf("\nDigite a chave a ser buscada no vetor:\n");
    scanf("%ld",&chave);
    contar((void *)chave);
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, (void *)contar, NULL);
    rc = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, (void *)contar2, NULL);
    rc = pthread_create(&t3, NULL, (void *)contar3, NULL);
    rc = pthread_create(&t4, NULL, (void *)contar4, NULL);
    rc = pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    rc = pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    rc = pthread_join(t3, NULL);
    rc = pthread_join(t4, NULL);
    printf("Ocorrencias: %ld",cont);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema não é de *race condition* mas sim de algorítimo mesmo. Você chama a função `contar()` duas vezes: uma na *thread* principal e outra na primeira *thread*. Veja:

```
contar((void *)chave);
int rc;
rc = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, (void *)contar, NULL);
```